# Scroll/Touch axis does not change if I rotate an iframe by 90 degree

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

My problem is I am using an iframe to load a page from different domain and trying to rotate the iframe by

```
transform:rotate(90deg)
```

But after rotation the top of the page goes to right and bottom to the left. So when I am trying to scroll the page inside iframe using mouse or touch it does not scroll if I drag the page from left to right but it responds only if I drag it vertically. So it seems like even if I am transforming the iframe its axis of scrolling is same as before transform. Is there any workaround so that I can scroll the iframe as respect to the rotated angle regardless of direction of the screen?